# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: C++ compilation

Tags: c++, architecture

I know this problem is incredibly washed up and asked a thousand times but I can't figure this out for the life of me. I continually get this error when trying to compile with my main function utilizing a specific function from my RatInMaze.cpp file. The searchStackSmart and searchStack don't cause any problems, but searchQueue does. Any thoughts? It might also be a problem with my makefile...RatInMaze.cpp compiles with the -c option, but main.cpp won't compile at all when I don't comment out the queue methods

Some terminal output:

```
Bretts-MacBook-Pro:HW4  make
g++ main.o Arraylist.o Myexception.cpp RatInMaze.cpp -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "RatInMaze::searchQueue(int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
Bretts-MacBook-Pro:HW4 g++ main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "RatInMaze::searchQueue(int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in cczPtT5h.o
  "RatInMaze::load(char (*) [15], int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in cczPtT5h.o
  "RatInMaze::print(bool)", referenced from:
      _main in cczPtT5h.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

RatInMaze.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "RatInMaze.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Stack.h"


using namespace std;

void RatInMaze::load(char [13][15], int dimX,int dimy)
{

}

void RatInMaze::print(bool found)
{
    if(found)
        cout<<"I found the exit! I traveled through "<<endl;//<<squaresTraveled<<" square(s) and the path contained "<< pathSize<<" square(s)"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Unable to find the exit."<<endl;//<<squaresTraveled<<" square(s)";
}




char map[13][15]={
        '0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
        '0','0','0','1','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0',
        '1','1','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
        '0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0' };

/*
Dumb Rat
While not at cheese, try moving right, then down, then left, then up each time in that order, adding to the stack each move and changing letter to indicate how we got there
If run into a road block, pop that last move off the stack and move back one space based on its letter (R,D,L,U) and continue

Smart Rat
Just like dumb, but check direction dx=toX-x each time and choose move based on that current situation

SearchQueue
"Sprawling rats"
start at the point, stack->push coordinates into queue stack->push(x) stack->push(y)
checke every direction possible and change the letter RLUD to indicate where you came from and stack->push each one of those pairs to the queue
When at the end, trace back based on the RLUD until you get to where you started ('4')

*/

bool RatInMaze::isValidIndex(int x, int y)
{
    // 12 x 14 array
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > 12 || y >14)
        return false;
    return true;
}

/*
SearchQueue
"Sprawling rats"
start at the point, stack->push coordinates into queue stack->push(x) stack->push(y)
checke every direction possible and change the letter RLUD to indicate where you came from 
and stack->push each one of those pairs to the queue
When at the end, trace back based on the RLUD until you get to where you started ('4')
*/

bool searchQueue(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
{

    int currentX;
    int currentY;
    int traveled;
    int thePath;

    //Matrix is 12x14, check dimensions
    if (fromX<0 || fromX>12 || fromY < 0 || fromY >14)
    {
        cout<<"Not valid starting point"<<endl;
        return false;
    }

    else if (toX<0 || toX >12 || toY <0 || toY >14)
    {
        cout<<"Not a valid ending point";
            return false;
    }

    //Valid index, we can proceed
    //Create Queue, starting points assigned
    Queue* ratQueue = new Queue();
    int x = fromX;
    int y = fromY;
    ratQueue->push(x);
    ratQueue->push(y);

    bool found = false;

    traveled=0;
    thePath=0;

    while (!found)
    {
        currentX=ratQueue->pop();
        currentY=ratQueue->pop();

        if (currentX==toX && currentY==toY)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        //Check right move
        if (map[currentX][currentY+1] < 1)
        {
            ratQueue->push(x);
            ratQueue->push(y+1);
            map[x][y+1]='R';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Check down move
        if (map[currentX+1][currentY] < 1)
        {
            ratQueue->push(x+1);
            ratQueue->push(y);
            map[x+1][y]='D';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Check left move
        if (map[currentX][currentY-1] < 1)
        {
            ratQueue->push(x);
            ratQueue->push(y-1);
            map[x][y-1]='L';
            traveled++;

        }

        //Check up move
        if (map[currentX-1][currentY] < 1)
        {
            ratQueue->push(x-1);
            ratQueue->push(y);
            map[x-1][y] = 'U';
            traveled++;
        }
    } //End while loop  



    //Cheese is now found

    x=toX;
    y=toY;

    while( !(x==fromX && y==fromY))
    {

        //Check if we came from left
        if (map[x][y]=='R')
        {
            map[x][y]='2';
            y=y-1;
            thePath++;
        }
        //Check if we came from above
        else if (map[x][y]=='D')
        {
            map[x][y]='2';
            x=x-1;
            thePath++;
        }
        //Check if we came from right
        else if (map[x][y]=='L')
        {
            map[x][y]='2';
            y=y+1;
            thePath++;
        }
        //Check if we came from below
        else if (map[x][y]=='U')
        {
            map[x][y]='2';
            x=x+1;
            thePath++;
        }

    }

    //Clean up array, leaving only 1s for the walls and 2 to show our path traveled
    for(int i=0; i <13; i++)
    {
        for( int j=0; i<15; j++)
        {
            if (map[i][j]!='1' && map[i][j]!='2')
                map[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    cout<<"Found the cheese! We traveled "<<traveled<<" squares and the path took "<<thePath<<" squares"<<endl;

    return true;
    //print(found, traveled, thePath);





} //End searchQueue method

bool RatInMaze::searchStack(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
{

    int backX;
    int backY;
    int traveled;
    int thePath;

    int x = fromY;
    int y = fromX;
    int temp = toY;
    toY=toX;
    toX=temp;

    //Matrix is 12x14, check dimensions
    if (fromX<0 || fromX>12 || fromY < 0 || fromY >14)
    {
        cout<<"Not valid starting point"<<endl;
        return false;
    }

    else if (toX<0 || toX >12 || toY <0 || toY >14)
    {
        cout<<"Not a valid ending pointz"<<endl;
            return false;
    }

    Stack* ratStack = new Stack();


             //throws error
    //Create stack? //ATTENTION
    // Load Map?    //ATTENTION

    //Set map variables

    map[x][y]='S'; //Mark starting point
    ratStack->push(y); //First coordinates in
    ratStack->push(x); //the stack are starting points

    for (int e=0; e<13; e++)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        for (int p=0; p<15; p++)
        {
            cout<<map[e][p]<<" ";
        }
    }

    //int iterations;
    //Load map? Attention
    while ( !(x==toX && y==toY))
    {
        if (ratStack->size() < -1000)
        {
            for (int e=0; e<13; e++)
            {
                cout<<"\n";
                for (int p=0; p<15; p++)
                {
                    cout<<map[e][p]<<" ";
                }
            }
        }
        //cout<<"Size is: "<<ratStack->size()<<endl;
        //cout<<"iteration: "<<iterations<<endl; iterations++;
        //Try to move right
        if(isValidIndex(x,y+1) && map[x][y+1] < 1)
        {   
            //stack->Push coordinates onto stack
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y+1;
            map[x][y]='R';
            traveled++;
        }
        //Try to move down
        else if(isValidIndex(x+1,y) && map[x+1][y] < 1)
        {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x+1;
            map[x][y]='D';
            traveled++;
        }
        //Try move left
        else if(isValidIndex(x,y-1) && map[x][y-1] < 1)
        {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y-1;
            map[x][y]='L';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Try move up 
        else if(isValidIndex(x-1,y) && map[x-1][y] < 1)
        {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x-1;
            map[x][y]='U';
            traveled++;
        }

        //Else you can't make any move, must retrace steps
        else
        {
            //Pop off last coordinates on stack to get the previous square
            backX = ratStack->pop();
            backY= ratStack->pop();

            //If we came from right, go back left, block off this square from revisiting
            if(map[backX][backY]=='R')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y-1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from above, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='D')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from left, go back right if we can, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='L')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from below, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='U')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }

            //return to top of loop and we are now at the spot we came from before running into jam
            //try to move right, down, left, up again as usual
            //if not, we pop off another set of coordinates and repeat until we can move
        }


    } //End while loop

    if (x==toX && y==toY)
    {   
        cout<<"We found the cheese! "<<"It took us "<<ratStack->size()<<"squares and we traveled through" << traveled<<endl;
        return true;
    }   
    else
        return false;

} //End method

char RatInMaze::checkDirection(int x, int y, int toX, int toY)
{

    // If down and right, return 0
    // If down and left, return 1
    // If up and right, return 2
    // If up and left, return 3
    // If just right return 4
    // If just left, return 5
    // If just up return 6
    // If just down, return 7
    // If coordinates, return 8

    if(x==toX)  // we are in the right row, need to go left or right
    {
        if(y==toY)
            return '9';
        else if (toY-y >0) //need to go right
            return '5';
        else
            return '6'; //need to go left

    }

    else if(y==toY) // we are in the right column, need to go up or down
    {
        if(toX-x>0) // need to go down
            return '8'; //go down
        else
            return '7';     //neeed to go up
    }

    else if(toX-x>0) //cheese is down
    {
        if(toY-y>0) //right
            return '0'; //right and down
        else        //up
            return '1'; //left and down
    }   

    else if(toX-x <0) //up
    {
        if(toY-y>0)     // right
            return '3';
        else 
            return '4';
    }
} //end check method




bool RatInMaze::searchStackSmart(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
{

    //Matrix is 12x14, check dimensions
    //Matrix is 12x14, check dimensions

    int x = fromY;
    int y = fromX;
    int temp = toY;
    toY=toX;
    toX=temp;


    if (fromX<0 || fromX>12 || fromY < 0 || fromY >14)
    {
        cout<<"Not valid starting point"<<endl;
        return false;
    }

    else if (toX<0 || toX >12 || toY <0 || toY >14)
    {
        cout<<"Not a valid ending point"<<endl;
            return false;
    }

    Stack* ratStack = new Stack();


    int backX;
    int backY;
    int traveled=0;

    ratStack->push(y);
    ratStack->push(x);
    bool found=false;

    while(!found)
    {
        char check =
        checkDirection(x,y,toX,toY);

        if (check='8')
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (check='0') //Down and right
        {
            //Try to move down then right

            //Try to move right
            if(isValidIndex(x,y+1) && map[x][y+1] < 1)
            {   
            //stack->Push coordinates onto stack
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y+1;
            map[x][y]='R';
            traveled++;
            }

            //Try to move down 

            if(isValidIndex(x+1,y) && map[x+1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x+1;
            map[x][y]='D';
            traveled++;
            }

        }
        else if (check='1') //Down and left
        {
            //Try down

            if(isValidIndex(x+1,y) && map[x+1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x+1;
            map[x][y]='D';
            traveled++;
            }

            //Try left
            if(isValidIndex(x,y-1) && map[x][y-1] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y-1;
            map[x][y]='L';
            traveled++;
            }


        }
        else if (check='2') //Up and right
        {
            //Try right
            if(isValidIndex(x,y+1) && map[x][y+1] < 1)
            {   
            //stack->Push coordinates onto stack
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y+1;
            map[x][y]='R';
            traveled++;
            }

            //Try up

            if(isValidIndex(x-1,y) && map[x-1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x-1;
            map[x][y]='U';
            traveled++;
            }
        }
        else if (check='3') //Up and left
        {
            //Try up

            if(isValidIndex(x-1,y) && map[x-1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x-1;
            map[x][y]='U';
            traveled++;
            }

            //Try left
            if(isValidIndex(x,y-1) && map[x][y-1] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y-1;
            map[x][y]='L';
            traveled++;
            }
        }
        else if (check='4') //Just right
        {
            //Try right
            if(isValidIndex(x,y+1) && map[x][y+1] < 1)
            {   
            //stack->Push coordinates onto stack
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y+1;
            map[x][y]='R';
            traveled++;
            }

            // if can't go right, try to go up or down
            //Try up
            else if(isValidIndex(x-1,y) && map[x-1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x-1;
            map[x][y]='U';
            traveled++;
            }
            //Try down

            else if(isValidIndex(x+1,y) && map[x+1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x+1;
            map[x][y]='D';
            traveled++;
            }



            else //can't move anywhere, movebackwards
            {
            //Pop off last coordinates on stack to get the previous square
            backX = ratStack->pop();
            backY= ratStack->pop();

            //If we came from right, go back left, block off this square from revisiting
            if(map[backX][backY]=='R')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y-1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from above, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='D')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from left, go back right if we can, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='L')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from below, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='U')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }

            //return to top of loop and we are now at the spot we came from before running into jam
            //try to move right, down, left, up again as usual
            //if not, we pop off another set of coordinates and repeat until we can move
            } //ELSE
         }//ORIGINAL ELSE IF

        else if (check='5') //Just left
        {

            //Try left
            if(isValidIndex(x,y-1) && map[x][y-1] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y-1;
            map[x][y]='L';
            traveled++;
            }
            // if can't go left, try to go up or down
            //Try up
            else if(isValidIndex(x-1,y) && map[x-1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x-1;
            map[x][y]='U';
            traveled++;
            }
            //Try down

            else if(isValidIndex(x+1,y) && map[x+1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x+1;
            map[x][y]='D';
            traveled++;
            }

            else //can't move anywhere, movebackwards
            {
            //Pop off last coordinates on stack to get the previous square
            backX = ratStack->pop();
            backY= ratStack->pop();

            //If we came from right, go back left, block off this square from revisiting
            if(map[backX][backY]=='R')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y-1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from above, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='D')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from left, go back right if we can, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='L')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from below, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='U')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }

            //return to top of loop and we are now at the spot we came from before running into jam
            //try to move right, down, left, up again as usual
            //if not, we pop off another set of coordinates and repeat until we can move
            } //ELSE
        }   //ORIGINAL ELSE IF
        else if (check='6') //Just up
        {

            //Try up
            if(isValidIndex(x-1,y) && map[x-1][y] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            x=x-1;
            map[x][y]='U';
            traveled++;
            }

            //Try right
            else if(isValidIndex(x,y+1) && map[x][y+1] < 1)
            {   
            //stack->Push coordinates onto stack
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y+1;
            map[x][y]='R';
            traveled++;
            }

            //Try left
            else if(isValidIndex(x,y-1) && map[x][y-1] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y-1;
            map[x][y]='L';
            traveled++;
            }
            else //can't move anywhere, movebackwards
            {
            //Pop off last coordinates on stack to get the previous square
            backX = ratStack->pop();
            backY= ratStack->pop();

            //If we came from right, go back left, block off this square from revisiting
            if(map[backX][backY]=='R')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y-1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from above, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='D')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from left, go back right if we can, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='L')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from below, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='U')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }


            } //ELSE
        } //ORIGINAL ELSE IF

        else if (check='7') //Just down
        {
                //TRY RIGHT
            if(isValidIndex(x,y+1) && map[x][y+1] < 1)
            {   
            //stack->Push coordinates onto stack
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y+1;
            map[x][y]='R';
            traveled++;
            }

                //TRY LEFT
            //Try left
            else if(isValidIndex(x,y-1) && map[x][y-1] < 1)
            {
            ratStack->push(y);
            ratStack->push(x);
            y=y-1;
            map[x][y]='L';
            traveled++;
            }
            else //can't move anywhere, movebackwards
            {
            //Pop off last coordinates on stack to get the previous square
            backX = ratStack->pop();
            backY= ratStack->pop();

            //If we came from right, go back left, block off this square from revisiting
            if(map[backX][backY]=='R')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y-1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from above, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='D')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from left, go back right if we can, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='L')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                y=y+1;
                traveled--;
            }
            //If we came from below, go back up, block off this square from revisiting
            else if(map[backX][backY]=='U')
            {
                map[backX][backY]='2';
                x=x+1;
                traveled--;
            }   

        } //ELSE END

    } //ORIGINAL ELSE IF END

    }//End while

        // Now we should be at the end

    if (x==toX && y==toY)
    {   
        cout<<"We found the cheese! "<<"It took us "<<ratStack->size()<<"squares and we traveled through" << traveled<<endl;
        return true;
    }   
    else
        return false;






}//End method
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "RatinMaze.h"
using namespace std;

void print_header (string h, int fromX,int fromY,int toX,int toY)  {
    cout << h << "from " << "(" << fromY << "," << fromX << ") to ("
         << toY << "," << toX << "):" << endl;
}

int main (){

        RatInMaze* rim = new RatInMaze();
    char maze[13][15]={
        '0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
        '0','0','0','1','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0',
        '1','1','0','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','1','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','1','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',
        '0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','1','0','1','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0',
        '0','0','0','0','1','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0','0' };

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Queue search ", -1,1,10,10);
    rim->print(rim->searchQueue(-1,1,10,10));
    //This causes a problem^

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Stack search ", 0,0,41,1);
    rim->print(rim->searchStack(0,0,41,1));

    int fromX = 0;
    int fromY = 7;
    int toX =  14;
    int toY =  6;

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Rat (stack) searching ",fromX,fromY,toX,toY);
    rim->print(rim->searchStack(fromX,fromY,toX,toY));

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Multiple rats searching ",fromX,fromY,toX,toY);
    rim->print(rim->searchQueue(fromX,fromY,toX,toY));
    //This causes a problem^

    rim->load(maze,13,15);
    print_header("Smart rat searching ",fromX,fromY,toX,toY);
    rim->print(rim->searchStackSmart(fromX,fromY,toX,toY));

}
```

Makefile

```
main: main.o Arraylist.o Myexception.o RatInMaze.o
    g++ main.o Arraylist.o Myexception.cpp RatInMaze.cpp -o main

main.o: main.cpp 
    g++ -c main.cpp RatInMaze.cpp
Arraylist.o: Arraylist.h Arraylist.cpp
    g++ -c Arraylist.cpp
Myexception.o: Myexception.cpp
    g++ -c Myexception.cpp

RatInMaze.o: RatInMaze.cpp Stack.h Queue.h Stack.cpp Queue.cpp
    g++ -c RatInMaze.cpp Stack.h Queue.h

Stack.o: Stack.h Stack.cpp
    g++ -c Stack.h

Queue.o: Queue.h Queue.cpp
    g++ -c Queue.h 

clean:
    rm main.o RatInMaze.o

tarfile:
    tar cvf Brett_Lindenberg_78363841.tar main.cpp  Arraylist.cpp Arraylist.h Myexception.cpp Myexception.h Chain.cpp Chain.h chainNode.cpp chainNode.h Linearlist.h Makefile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to be embarrassed at how simple your problem is.

You defined:

```
bool searchQueue(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
```

You need to change that to:

```
bool RatInMaze::searchQueue(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY)
```

As it stands right now, you've declared a function named `RatInMaze::searchQueue`, but defined a function named `::searchQueue` (i.e., the `searchQueue` you defined isn't a member of `RatInMaze`).